# spring boot application.properties files does not autocomplete the code

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've created a spring project in IntelliJ IDE with Spring Initializr.
When I tried to modify the application.properties file, I realized that it does not autocomplete the code, I mean, it does not show the options like when you type "In" and shows "Integer".
Also, if I try to run the app, `localhost:8080/index.html` is redirected to `http://localhost:8080/login`

Any idea about what the problem is? 
thanks

just realized that import lombok.Data; does not highlight also, even with the dependency is set
[image]

Answer (score 3):

To your first question:

> ...it does not autocomplete the code

You should make sure your "Spring Boot" plugin is enabled. Look [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html?_ga=2.227907605.929104495.1579393689-979037735.1579393689) for how to manage plugins in Intellij IDEA.

To your second question:

> `localhost:8080/index.html` is redirected to `http://localhost:8080/login`

To fix your redirect problem, you should remove your maven dependency for spring-starter-security (as already stated by [user9717940](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9717940/user9717940)). However, it could be caused by other security-related dependencies, like something Oauth. Go to your maven pom.xml file and look for something like the snippet below and remove it from your dependencies section.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @geekTechique about the two questions advice, it have a lot of sense.

Comment: About the second problem, i already had the "Spring Assistant" plugin installed (i've didn't saw any called "Spring Boot") which is the most installed one. What i've noticed now is that the "application.properties" file code is highlighted while the IDE is loading, but the highlight turns off once loaded.

Comment: For clarification, do other filetypes, like .java, show autocompletion in your IDE?

Comment: just realized that import lombok.Data; does not highlight also, even with the dependency is set, i've edited the question and added a pic

Comment: In intellij, dependencies can be grayed out if they aren't used. Have you tried using some type of Lombok annotation, like `@Data` above your class name to make use of the Lombok import?

Comment: ops!, yes that it

Comment: Glad I could help. If you feel like I've given a useful answer to your question, please don't forget to mark it as completed.

Answer (score 1):

To your second question: you probably have spring-boot-starter-security within your dependencies. It secures your application by default and your request to index.html is intercepted and redirected to login page. You should see password in log when application is starting.